# How use lapply on list of data frames and using a function that takes the ID name of the list

Tags: r

I have the following lists of data frame:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4))
df <- list(FOO=d1, BAR=d2)
```

Which looks like this:

```
> df
$FOO
  y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6

$BAR
  y1 y2
1  3  6
2  2  5
3  1  4
```

And a function that plot each individual data frame and named them based on list ID:

```
plot_df_func <- function(basename="QUX",in_df) {
    outfile <- paste(basename,".png",sep="")

    png(outfile)
    plot(in_df,main=basename)
    dev.off()
}
```

How can I use `lapply` in this case?

At the end of the day it will have "FOO.png" and "BAR.png".

I tried this but failed:

```
> lapply(df, plot_df_func) 
Error in plot(in_df, main = basename) : 
  argument "in_df" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: why not `lapply(df, plot_df_func)`

Comment: @platfort: that won't do because it can't recognize `FOO` and `BAR` which i s needed by the function.

Comment: Could also do `lapply(names(df), function(x) plot_df_func(x, df[[x]]))`

Comment: From the last post and from here, I thought your first argument should be `lapply(df, ` instead of looping over the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `for` loop. In my opinion, a `for` loop is always preferable if you want only side effects (like plots or files) and no return value.

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4))
df <- list(FOO=d1, BAR=d2)

plot_df_func <- function(basename="QUX",in_df) {
  #outfile <- paste(basename,".png",sep="")

  #png(outfile)
  plot(in_df,main=basename)
  #dev.off()
}

layout(1:2)
for (i in names(df)) plot_df_func(i, df[[i]])
```

[image: resulting plot]